# How to create similar video in Blender with particle systems

Tags: particles

I want to create a similar video in Blender but I don't have much knowledge in Blender.
Thanks.

[image]

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_D6E07MffiX6KlWE0wVE9sZ96jau7C8-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like small white dots moving on the surface of transparent spheres, a simple way to recreate that could be to mix an *Emission* with a *Transparent* node, with a *Voronoi Texture* node as factor. To make them move, just use the *Rotation* values of the Mapping node. As you have dots going in different directions, you could simply duplicate the sphere, leave the duplication at the same place, rotate it a bit (<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>), duplicate its material, change the *Mapping* values a bit, you'll have a group of new dots moving differently.

[image]